# Array back to begin values C#

Tags: c#, arrays, default

I was working with a array in C# and I want it to have its default values again i tried creating a second array as following:

```
static readonly int[] defmenuItemsParInt = { 60, 60, 0 };
static int[] menuItemsParInt = defmenuItemsParInt;
```

for some reason this changed the default array aswell so i tried:

```
static int[] menuItemsParInt = { 60, 60, 0 };
static readonly int[] defmenuItemsParInt = menuItemsParInt;
```

(the arrays are declared above the main class)

both I used my reset function:

```
static void reset()
        {
            menuItemsParInt = defmenuItemsParInt;
        }
```

these methods didnt work is there a easier method or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: So are you trying to convert int array to string array or other way around?

Comment: Your code currently provided wouldnt compile - so, no this is definately wrong.  what exactly are you trying to do? You have ints on one and string on the other..

Comment: Arrays are assigned by reference. You need to copy it.

Comment: `defmenuItemsParInt` and `menuItemsParInt` refer to the same array. You need to copy the items from one array to the other.

Comment: lol i copied the wrong part of the code sorry guys i editted it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is use CopyTo function like below. The CopyTo function copies all the elements of the array defmenuItemsParInt to the destination array mentioned as the first argument. This way, since as the elements are only getting copied, it won't affect the default array in any case.

```
static readonly string[] defmenuItemsParInt = { 60, 60, 0 };
static string[] menuItemsParInt = new int[defmenuItemsParInt.Length];
defmenuItemsParInt.CopyTo(menuItemsParInt, 0);
```

Comment: @CodeCaster The CopyTo function copies all the elements of the array defmenuItemsParInt to the destination array mentioned as the first argument. This way, since as the elements are only getting copied, it won't affect the default array in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Objects (arrays included) in C# are [stored by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c). This implies that when you write `menuItemsParInt = defmenuItemsParInt` you are not copying the object data, but a reference to it. As a result both identifiers (`menuItemsParInt` and  `defmenuItemsParInt`) point to the same data.

To make a copy of the data in the array you can use [`Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
static int[] menuItemsParInt = (int[])defmenuItemsParInt.Clone();
```

The same should be done when reverting the changes:

```
static void reset()
{
    menuItemsParInt = (int[])defmenuItemsParInt.Clone();
}
```

Comment: the only answer which actually explains the fault in OP's approach using the `=` operator

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the elements because your second array is actually pointing at them. Try this instead:

```
string[] defmenuItemsParInt = { "60", "60", "0" };
int[] menuItemsParInt = (int[]) defmenuItemsParInt.Clone();´
```

This makes a clone of your initial array. Hope it helps in any way.